# OAuth response is different when called from apex and browser

Tags: api, oauth

I am doing a basic OAuth, I am getting 2 different errors when I try calling api from browser and from my apex code. 
When the api is called from the browser it requires username and password for authentication and respond back with error `[Order] Order Sales+Order/0011 not found.` my api endpoint is `http://mydomain.com/integration/{code}/orders/Sales+Order/0011`

While trying the same end point from my apex code I am getting `System.HttpResponse[Status=Bad Request, StatusCode=400]`

My apex code

```
String username = 'xyz';
String password = 'abc';
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('http://mydomain.com/integration/{code}/orders/Sales+Order/0011');
req.setMethod('GET');
Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);
String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
Http http = new Http(); 
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
```

My I know what I am missing out in the above code. The Api url is having space between Sales Order, I am replacing the space with '+'. Is this the reason for the above error. Please guide me the best solution.

Comment: Is your endpoint a force.com hosted site/webservice?

Comment: It is a web service.

Comment: Have you tried using Postman or any other rest client to see of the webservice actually works?